# Prove if $ a, z \in \mathbb C $ and $ |z|=1 $, then $ \frac{|z-a|}{|1-\bar{a}z|} =1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Prove that if $ a, z \in \mathbb{C} $ and $ |z|=1 $, then : $$ \frac{|z-a|}{|1-\bar{a}z|} =1$$

I don't know where to start.
I tried using $|z|$ instead of $1$ , conjugate, square them, etc.

Comment: $|e^{i\theta} z| = |z|$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Multiply the denominator with $1 = |\overline{z}|$ and use the fact that $|x| = |\overline{x}|$.

Answer (score 2):

As long as $a \neq z$ you have $1-\bar{a}z \neq 0$, because $z^{-1} = \bar{z}$. Then the right hand side is defined and
\begin{align*}
 \frac{|z-a|}{|1-\bar{a}z|} = 1
 &\iff |z-a| = |1-\bar{a}z| \\
 &\iff |z-a|^2 = (1-\bar{a}z)^2 \\
 &\iff (z-a)\overline{(z-a)} = (1-\bar{a}z)\overline{(1-\bar{a}z}) \\
 &\iff (z-a)(\bar{z}-\bar{a}) = (1-\bar{a}z)(1-a\bar{z}) \\
 &\iff  |z|^2 \color{red}{-a\bar{z} - \bar{a}z} + |a|^2
        = 1 \color{red}{-\bar{a}z - a\bar{z}} + |a|^2 |z|^2 \\
 &\iff  |z|^2 + |a|^2 = 1 + |a|^2 |z|^2,
\end{align*}
which holds because $|z| = 1$.

Comment: how to get from the second step to the last step?

Comment: I added some more steps.

Comment: what property makes $ a \bar{z} + \bar{a} z =0 $? thanks for you patience

Comment: This does not hold. Instead, notice that on both sides of the equality we have the torm $-a\bar{z}-\bar{a}z$. So what we do is adding $a\bar{z}+\bar{a}z$ to both sides of the equation. I put some colors in the equation to highlight the parts.

Comment: Does this hold for $|z|<1$ as well?